# Question about integration with a transcedental function

Tags: integration, functions

Lets say $\int$$x(e^x$$^2+2)dx$ my professor said that you need to distribute X first because its a transcedental function and not simply $u$$=x^2$ where $du=2x$. now is $lnx^2$ a transcedental function? if it is in the problem $\int$$\frac{dx}{x(2-lnx^2)}$ should I distribute x in the denominator?